# CakePHP input label and error before input field

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to have the `<label>` and `<div class="error-message">` show up BEFORE the `<input>` when doing `$this->Form->input()`

Can someone tell me how to do this?

To re-iterate.

This is what happens now:

```
<input>
<div class="error-message">Some error</div>
<label>Some label</label>
```

What I want to happen:

```
<div class="error-message">Some error</div>
<label>Some label</label>
<input>
```

Comment: `echo "the and ".$this->Form->input()` ... please clarify your question

Comment: Oi, half my question disappeared! Hang on :)

Comment: I fixed it. You needed the `\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this to the $options for the relevant input fields:

```
'format' => array('error', 'before', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'after')
```